# Modify .suo file

Tags: visual-studio, suo

I need to modify a .suo file.

Basically, I have a client-server application. The client needs a "cookie" to log into the server, which is generated every day and retrieved on the client machine by another process. This "cookie" needs to be set in the "Debugging Command Arguments".

I want to automate this process by modifying the .suo file directly through another app / script. Is there a way I can do this?

I looked at [Tool to view the contents of the Solution User Options file (.suo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052/tool-to-view-the-contents-of-the-solution-user-options-file-suo), but that did not help much. I have no idea about those methods and would need a bit more direction.

Comment: how about putting the cookie in a config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the Command Line Debug parameters are stored in the proj.user file, yeah?  That's just an XML file and should be easy enough to modify.

Comment: You are right. Pretty daft of me to not even think of that :)
Thanks!