# Visual Studio 2015 RC missing using option in quick actions

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials, codemaid

I have no idea what changed, but either using Ctrl+. or right clicking to bring up the quick actions in VS2015 RC (14.0.22823.1) on a token that I haven't added the right using statement used to give me an option to automatically add it for me, along with options to create a new class and a few other things.

The last couple days it's no longer giving me the option to add the using statement for me (I use this shortcut all the time). It still has all the other options.

Anyone else run into this? I recently installed Web Essentials 2015.0 RC and Code Maid (code maid was causing problems so I removed it). Could one of those affect it?

Comment: And I just noticed this is only on one of my solutions (the main one I'm working on right now). A brand new solution/project works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem and solved it by renaming the `.suo` file in `ProjectName\.vs\ProjectName\v14` to something VS will not find, like `.suo.bak`.

This will reset your [project specific preferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx), like open files, solution explorer state etc. Make a backup of the file or rename it so you can go back if you are missing something important.

If everything works afterwards you can simply delete the renamed file, VS will create a new one.

Comment: I solved my problem with your solution, thank you. Is there any chance you can explain what's going on with this `.suo` file so that it makes the option disappear in VS ?

Comment: No, sorry. The file is in a proprietary binary format and "stores IDE state" (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2231114/7114094) answer). Your guess is as good as mine...