# Are suo (solution option) files portable? or tied a user or to that particular instance of the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, suo

In Visual studio 2008 -- For my particular project, I only care about a subset of a solution. I handle this by unloading the projects I don't need. I know these settings are saved in suo. So what I'd like to do is save off the suo file with these settings for later use so that when I (or someone else on my team) checks out the code, instead of seeing the entire solution, they can apply this suo file and just the subset they care about without having to manually unload each project.

Is this possible, or are suo files tied to a specific user or directory or some such? How portable are these files?

Comment: No guarantees, it is a completely undocumented file format.  Try it, the worst that could happen is that VS crashes or puts a window out of range off the screen.

Comment: @Hans, I'll try it when I get a chance. I don't have two instances of the rather large solution checked out at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out a second copy of my solution and applied a suo file from another checked out copy. The projects unloaded in the original were also unloaded in the newly checked out copy after applying the original suo. So the suo seems to be somewhat transplantable to different instances of your solution.

Still haven't prove definitively whether suo is tied to a specific user account and I assume it won't work if your solution file gets too far from the solution originally used to create the suo.

Answer (score 0):

When your team mates check-out your version of the .suo they will overwrite a lot of other options, too. For a list see: my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24721006/1926353) to another stackoverflow question.

Maybe you should just create a second solution, that only contains the subset of projects.