# Where does Visual Studio 2008 store bookmarks and batch build selection for a C++ solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, solution

I often move my Visual Studio 2008 C++ solutions from computer to computer. I wrote a small batch script that "cleans up" the following temp files before I zip all files. I do it to speed up the zip'ing process and also to save on space when backing up & archiving solutions. For instance, some auxiliary intellisense files can grow quite large.

The script removes all files with the following extensions:

```
.ncb, .suo, .sdf, .aps, .bsc, .log, .tlog, .user, .sbr
```

It works fine, except that I have two minor issues. When I remove those files it also removes:

1) All my batch build selections -- see screenshot.

2) All bookmarks that I set up in my projects.

[image]

So I was wondering, where are those stored in the solution so I can preserve them?

Comment: Did you check solution folder for a hidden .vs directory?

Comment: @SvSv: I don't think VS2008 creates it. So, no, there's no such.

Comment: Have to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24721006/843732) to my own question. It's in the `.suo` file.