# Visual Studio .suo file gets corrupted after each reload

Tags: visual-studio-2017, project

I am working with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 (I use C++). But every time when I save the project, close VS and reload the next day, Visual Studio says, the project is unloaded and not acessible. I then have to open the code files and redo all the linking with the library stuff.  I found out,  that the project's .suo file is filled with bullshit and strange symbols, but it should be a readable XML file. Do you know why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

.suo is not a readable XML file. See [Solution User Options (.Suo) File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx):

> The solution user options (.suo) file is a structured storage, or
>   compound, file stored in a binary format.

If you want to explore it see [Tool to view the contents of the Solution User Options file (.suo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052/tool-to-view-the-contents-of-the-solution-user-options-file-suo)